How to manage a navbar with nextjs 14
I have a nextjs project v14. I would like to make a Navbar and use it into the layout of the root of /app folder. So I made the component and used it into the layout.
I found out there ia one serious problem: The component renders only the first time and when I navigate into the app I cannot watch the pathname in order to change the style of the navbar voice I selected.
The RootLayout looks like this:
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar>{children}</Navbar>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

And Navbar is this:
import { NextPage } from "next";
import Link from "next/link";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { useTranslation } from "../i18n";
import React, { useMemo } from "react";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Navbar: NextPage<Props> = async ({ children }) => {
  const headersList = headers();
  const url = headersList.get("referer") || "";
  //It's not the best way to get the pathname, I know but couldn't find a different way
  const pathname = useMemo(() => `/${url.split("/").at(-1)}`, [url]);
  const { t } = await useTranslation("it", "common");

  return (
    <>
        <nav className="px-4 py-4 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-200 absolute h-24 w-full z-50 align-middle justify-center">
          <div className="h-full flex">
            <div className="flex w-full justify-between lg:justify-center my-auto">
              <NavbarItem
                name={t("NAVBAR.HOME")}
                to="/"
                isSelected={pathname === "/"}
              />
              <NavbarItem
                name={t("NAVBAR.PROJECTS")}
                to="/projects"
                isSelected={pathname === "/projects"}
              />
              <NavbarItem
                name={t("NAVBAR.INFOS")}
                to="/about-me"
                isSelected={pathname === "/about-me"}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

const NavbarItem: NextPage<{
  name: string;
  to: string;
  isSelected: boolean;
}> = ({ name, to, isSelected }) => {
  return (
    <Link locale={"en"} href={to}>
      <h1
        className={`lg:text-xl text-lg px-2 lg:px-2 lg:mx-14 py-2 cursor-pointer hover:underline select-none w-24 lg:w-44 flex justify-center ${
          isSelected
            ? "bg-gray-300/25 rounded-xl text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-100 font-bold"
            : ""
        }`}
      >{`${name}`}</h1>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

I would like to avoid to make it a client component and use it in the respective pages, because in that case I need to import it into every page, which is not very nice in my opinion.
Is it possible to manage the selection of the current page into the Navbar component?
p.s. There also can be the possibility to show it conditionally based on routes or other conditions.

How are you receiving locale in RootLayout? what are you using for locale management? Is your top-level folder under app folder called something like [locale]?

I am going to update the question: i have just solved the issue about the language with this guide: https://locize.com/blog/next-app-dir-i18n/

You said you would like to avoid making it a client component but I think that is the solution here. See this comment https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704#issuecomment-1548525955 (or the whole issue thread :D)

@errnesto I think there need to make a client component. They have my same problem. Cannot highlight the selected item in the navbar. That sounds strange but yeah.

Personally i manage the NavBar and Footer like this
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="es">
      <head>

      </head>
      <body>
        <NavBar />
          { children }
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

So you probably can solve this problem with Zustand, in every page the user enter save a key and consume on your NavBar to do what you want
I recommended to you Zustand because is lightweight but if you already manage a global state with other package, its the same way
Hope you find this helpful

So basically when you navigate around the app you set a global state right? also for the language?

Exactly, when you enter on any page you can set a KEY to identify that specific page.
The lnaguage can manage directly on the NavBar (This for common user-friendly location) or any other page and as equal with the KEY for page, save a value than consume to handle everythong releated about that
In other words think about this solution like a global state of your app and you can check make any state what you nedd and check inside any component/page/hook
Already its the definition of Zustand and any other global state manager

I see. The fact is that I don't like to do that in every page. With the _app.tsx file I could do it there and it was the same for the entire app. I would like something like that
